# OpenModelica (v1.13.0): FMU export is broken - static.log: No such file or directory

Tags: modeling, ode, modelica, openmodelica, fmi

When I try to export an FMU from OpenModelica(v1.13.0), the following error is generated:

```
[3] 17:10:36 Scripting Error
Error opening file: C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Local\Temp\OpenModelica\OMEdit\test\test.fmutmp/resources/static.log: No such file or directory.
```

It worked in v1.12.0, can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a space in your user name? If so, that is the problem.
Change the working directory in OMEdit to a place with no space in it or special characters. Via Tools->Options.

Comment: Yea that was the problem. Changing the working directory solved the issue. Thanks!